# Reading data from Firebase to TableView

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, tableview

I try to fetch the data from my database into a `TableView`.
When I access the data, I get the error: "Type 'Any' has no subscript members". This is the code that doesn't work:

```
        let title = snapshot.value!["Title"] as! String
        let location = snapshot.value!["Location"] as! String
        let date = snapshot.value!["Date"] as! String
```

I get the same error for each individual row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are making the firebase call inside your TableViewController you can do this inside your Firebase Listener:

```
if let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary{
    if let titleValue = value["Title"] as? String{
         title = titleValue
    }
    if let locationValue = value["Location"] as? String{
         location = locationValue
    }
    if let dateValue = value["Date"] as? String{
         date = dateValue
    }
}
```

And then obviously you'd have `else`if it fails set these variables back to a default value.

Answer (score 0):

`snapshot.value` is of type `Any?`.

Try doing this ([optional unwrapping & type casting](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-ID338)):

```
if let valueDictionary = snapshot.value as? [AnyHashable:String]
{
    let title = valueDictionary["Title"]
    let location = valueDictionary["Location"]
    let date = snapshot.value!["Date"]
}
```

If there are other types in that dictionary (e.g. a native `Date` object instead of a `String`), declare the dictionary as `[AnyHashable:Any]` and then you'll need to explicitly set the type for your variables as you did before (e.g. `let title = valueDictionary["Title"] as! String`)